# superuser inbox not posting new messages

Tags: support

Since yesterday, my superuser inbox is no longer receiving updates to questions where I contributed. That is, if I am to leave a comment and then another user were to leave a subsequent comment, I am not receiving an update in my inbox that another user has posted a comment or solution. It is only posting messages for questions I originate.

Is there a setting in superuser I might have inadvertently changed that affects my inbox behavior?

Comment: If it not your question then you will only get notified if the commenter uses @brian

Comment: Thanks, @DavidPostill, I did not know that.

Comment: [You may want to explicitly follow some posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/355310).

Comment: Thanks, @Kamil Maciorowski. I did not realize this was possible

Answer (score 1):

This is when you get notifications about comments:

- when it's your own question/answer
- if you're subscribed to question/answer. Subscribing to question also notifies you about edits, answers and when it's closed.
- if someone pings you with `@name`
- whenever you add a comment under a question/answer and noone else apart from the author does

The last case is kind of confusing and a reason why you may have thought it's always automatic. Not sure why they implemented it like that, but what's missing for me is some kind of autosubscription mechanism to all questions where you comment.